# Sita's reply to Maha Sati Anasuya-Advice on Stri-Dharma

Tags: ramayana, sita

Sri Rama and his consort Sita, met Maharishi Atri at the Maharishi's hermitage, during the early part of their exile. After introducing his wife Anasuya as a great ascetic, the Maharishi requested Sri Rama to send Sita to his wife Anasuya.

After  making Sita feel comfortable, 
Maha Sati Anasuya gave Sita a lot of advice on the role and responsibilities of a devoted wife( details are given in Book II : Ayodhya Kanda - Book Of Ayodhya Chapter[Sarga] 117). Sita  reverentially accepted the advice given by Maha Sati Anasuya and thereafter, gave a reply. What is the reply given by Sita to Maha Sati Anasuya, after receiving the advice on Stri-Dharma?

Comment: Add the woman tag and the Dharma tag.. the mythology tag seems irrelevant here.

Comment: A Q about Stri (woman) and Dharma will not be tagged with those two tags? This is clearly wrong tagging if u ask me.

Answer (score 4):

Sita accepted all the advice given by Maha Sati Anasuya, on Stri-Dharma and Satitva, with great devotion.The reply given by Sita to Maha Sati Anasuya, is explained as under:-

> सा तु एवम् उक्ता वैदेही अनसूयान् असूयया |
>
> प्रतिपूज्य वचो मन्दम् प्रवक्तुम् उपचक्रमे || २-११८-१
>
> Anasuya having spoken thus, Seetha without any jealousy, full of reverence for her, addressed her gently as follows:
>
> न एतद् आश्चर्यम् आर्याया यन् माम् त्वम् अनुभाषसे |
>
> विदितम् तु मम अप्य् एतद् यथा नार्याः पतिर् गुरुः || २-११८-२
>
> It is not a surprise that a venerable woman like  you, talk to me like this, for, I know well that a husband is a respectable person for a woman."
>
> यद्य् अप्य् एष भवेद् भर्ता मम आर्ये वृत्त वर्जितः |
>
> अद्वैधम् उपवर्तव्यः तथा अप्य् एष मया भवेत् || २-११८-३
>
> "O, venerable woman! Even if my husband be without fortune, he should unhesitatingly be obeyed by me."
>
> किम् पुनर् यो गुण श्लाघ्यः सानुक्रोशो जित इन्द्रियः |
>
> स्थिर अनुरागो धर्म आत्मा मातृ वर्ती पितृ प्रियः || २-११८-४
>
> "How much more, if he be renowned for his virtues, compassionate, master of my heart, who is ever affectionate, a religious person, manifests the tenderness of a mother and a father to me."
>
> याम् वृत्तिम् वर्तते रामः कौसल्यायाम् महा बलः |
>
> ताम् एव नृप नारीणाम् अन्यासाम् अपि वर्तते || २-११८-५
>
> The exceedingly strong Rama bears himself to all other Queens, as he exercises his behaviour towards his mother, Kausalya."
>
> सकृद् दृष्टासु अपि स्त्रीषु नृपेण नृप वत्सलः |
>
> मातृवद् वर्तते वीरो मानम् उत्सृज्य धर्मवित् || २-११८-६
>
> "The valiant and pious Rama who is devoted to Dasartha and free from all sense of importance treats all those women as his mothers on whom Dasaratha has even once bestowed a single glance."
>
> आगग्च्छन्त्याः च विजनम् वनम् एवम् भय आवहम् |
>
> समाहितम् हि मे श्वश्र्वा हृदये यत् स्थितम् महत् || २-११८-७
>
> "While departing for the lonely and fearful forest, my mother-in-law imparted a great message to me, which I have inscribed in my heart."
>
> प्राणि प्रदान काले च यत् पुरा तु अग्नि सम्निधौ |
>
> अनुशिष्टा जनन्या अस्मि वाक्यम् तद् अपि मे धृतम् || २-११८-८
>
> "What my mother taught me when witnessed by the fire, earlier at the time of my marriage with Rama, I shall always remember them."
>
> नवी कृतम् तु तत् सर्वम् वाक्यैः ते धर्म चारिणि |
>
> पति शुश्रूषणान् नार्याः तपो न अन्यद् विधीयते || २-११८-९
>
> "O, virtuous woman! By your words, all that is being renewed. No austerity, other than obedience to one's husband is decreed for a woman."
>
> सावित्री पति शुश्रूषाम् कृत्वा स्वर्गे महीयते ||
>
> तथा वृत्तिः च याता त्वम् पति शुश्रूषया दिवम् || २-११८-१०
>
> Savitri is now highly honoured in heaven, for having served her lord faithfully in heaven, You too, having followed this, will proceed to heaven, in showing obedience to your husband."
>
> SAvitri was the celebrated wife of Prince Satyavan.
>
> वरिष्ठा सर्व नारीणाम् एषा च दिवि देवता |
>
> रोहिणी च विना चन्द्रम् मुहूर्तम् अपि दृश्यते || २-११८-११
>
> "This goddess Rohini, the excellent among all women, is not seen without the moon even for a single moment in the sky."
>
> एवम् विधाः च प्रवराः स्त्रियो भर्तृ दृढ व्रताः |
>
> देव लोके महीयन्ते पुण्येन स्वेन कर्मणा || २-११८-१२
>
> "Such excellent women, devoted to their husbands, and by their meritorious deeds, are highly honoured in heaven."

Reference: Valmiki Ramayana , Book II Ayodhya Kanda - Book Of Ayodhya Chapter[Sarga] 118

Reference link:- http://www.valmikiramayan.net/utf8/ayodhya/sarga118/ayodhya_118_frame.htm